# PHP - Variable or function call as key in array initializer

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP, is it valid to use a variable or function return value as a key when initializing an array? I have tested it and it works, but I can't find any mention in any tutorials or documentation, which I find weird. For example:

```
function getKey() {
    return 'foo';
}
$foo = 'bar';
$array = [
    'key' => 'val',
    $foo => 'val',
    getKey() => 'val'
];
```

Comment: You're not using the function call as the key; you're using the value that is returned by that function call... likewise, you're not using the variable, you're using the value stored in that variable at the point where you define the array

Comment: Makes sense, I'm coming from JS, I understand that associative arrays in PHP are very different than JS objects, but being able to do this seemed strange at first since [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) were only added recently in JS, and the documentation wasn't very clear.